# Codes for call recording in android

Tags: android

I am making and application that records calls. Here is my code to record a call and save the file in the SD card under songs folder. But the problem is that this code was working fine but later it is not working. I cannot find what is the problem. Can you please help me out?

My Broad cast receiver:

```
public class BrCallReceive extends BroadcastReceiver {

      @Override
    public void onReceive(Context c, Intent i) {

        Bundle extras = i.getExtras();
        Intent x = new Intent (c, EavesDropperActivity.class);
        x.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        if (extras != null) {
            String state = extras.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
            Log.w("DEBUG", state);
            if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
                Log.w("DEBUG", "MATCHES");
                Toast.makeText(c, "Launching record APP !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                c.startActivity(x);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My Recording activity:

```
public class EavesDropperActivity extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    MediaRecorder m_recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    TelephonyManager t_manager ;
    PhoneStateListener p_listener ;
    String record_state;
    Uri file;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                "Executing Activity",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        t_manager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService (Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        p_listener = new PhoneStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCallStateChanged (int state, String incomingNumber) {
                switch (state) {
                    case (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE)     :
                        stop_recorder();

                        //t_manager.listen(p_listener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
                        //finish();
                        break;

                    case (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK)     :

                        start_recorder();

                        break;
                    case (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING)     :

                        break;

                }
            }
        };
        t_manager.listen(p_listener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
        return;
    }

    public void start_recorder () {
        m_recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        m_recorder.setOutputFormat(OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        m_recorder.setOutputFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/songs/audionew.3gpp");
        m_recorder.setAudioEncoder(AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

        try {
            m_recorder.prepare();
            m_recorder.start();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void stop_recorder () {
        m_recorder.stop();
        m_recorder.release();
        Uri file = Uri.fromFile(
                new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"/songs/audionew.3gpp"));
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                "record stored at " + file.toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        t_manager.listen(p_listener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
        finish();
    }
}
```

My manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.testapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />    

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.testapp.EavesDropperActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name="BrCallReceive" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" >
                </action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: any logcat? what do you exactly mean when you say it's stopped working and it used to work before?

Comment: the thing is that when i am installing the apk on my device and running it it is not working. Earlier the same code was able to record phone calls. But now after installing nothing is happening. The apk is just installed and nothing is happening.

Comment: my device is android 4.1.2

Comment: Logcat would be useful. Is the activity getting launched? Before that, is the receiver getting triggered? Is extras null?

Comment: ya i checked my log cat just now. It is not showing any log detail. I think the broadcast receiver is not getting activated wile i am calling my phone. But how to make my receiver functional now.? I think thats the problem.Bro i dont think activity will get launched. the codes are as such there will be no icon of this app. The broadcast receiver should work in background and will be invoked when call is made or received. And we can get the app in the application manager , no where else

Comment: How do you know your broadcast receiver is not working? Place a Log message inside onReceive() right at the beginning. That's a good starting point.

Comment: Sir i Just checked by placing log at beginning of receiver but my log cat is empty. It is not showing any info while calls. And onw more thing i noticed that i application manager of my device when i open this app the "FoRCE STOP" button is disabled. I never did this.then How? I trid installing this app many times but still that button is already disabled. what does that signify?

Comment: Earlier the same code was able to record phone calls so now what have you changed??

Comment: nothing i hv changed. that is the problem. but still it is not working. can you check these codes in your device?

Answer (score 1):

**I think the broadcast receiver is not getting activated wile i am calling my phone.**

How do you know your broadcast receiver is not working? Place a Log message inside onReceive() right at the beginning. It might be that your `extras == null`

**But how to make my receiver functional now?**

Check out [example #5](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html) and just follow the same steps.

**Bro i dont think activity will get launched.**

Well, it does: You are starting it in your onReceive():

```
Intent x = new Intent (c, EavesDropperActivity.class);
c.startActivity(x);
```

However, you are not setting any content in your Activity i.e no UI screen is presented because you have this line commented in `onCreate()` of `EavesDropperActivity` Activity:

```
//setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

So, you need to think hard on what you are trying to achieve in `EavesDropperActivity`

HTH.

Comment: I have put my main.xml as commented because i dont want to do anything wid that. So i have modified my manifest file. In EavesDropperActivity i am jus recording and stopping and saving the file in sd card. So thats why i have put that commented. And i have also cheked by putting the log in onreceiver but no log is being shown in log cat.

Comment: try the code on the device that was working before. May be the device you are using to test now is broken. If the code did not change, then the test device is a suspect.

Comment: If you are just recording and stopping and saving the file in sd card, you should pick a started IntentService instead of an Activity. People typically use Activity when they have to display some UI elements and get user's input on something. Since you don't need any user's intervention, consider a Service. But this still does not explain why the code was working on some previous device and not working on your new device.

Answer (score 0):

Put this

```
  <android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>


<action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
```

in mainfest file for  broadcast receiver.

Answer (score 0):

Add your package name to your receiver class as,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.testapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />    

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.testapp.EavesDropperActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name="com.example.testapp.BrCallReceive" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" >
                </action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
```